# Floating stick graph in Plotly

Tags: plotly

How can I generate this type of 'floating stick' (or 'high/low'?) chart using [Plotly](https://plot.ly/)? I've had a look through the examples and can't find anything quite the same - most importantly setting up bars/sticks which don't begin at zero.

Note that the lines are not error bars.

[image: Example plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to make stick charts is with negative offsets on [asymmetric error bars](https://plot.ly/python/error-bars/#Asymmetric-Error-Bars) that have [zero width](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#ErrorY-width). Here's an example:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.graph_objs import ErrorY, Scatter

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [4, 7, 5, 9]
stick_top = [10, 6, 7, 11]
stick_bottom = [6, 4, 3, 4]

error_bar_positive_offset = [si - yi for (yi, si) in zip(y, stick_top)]
error_bar_negative_offset = [yi - si for (yi, si) in zip(y, stick_bottom)]

py.plot([
    Scatter(x=x, y=y, mode='markers',
        error_y=ErrorY(
            symmetric=False, 
            array=error_bar_positive_offset, 
            arrayminus=error_bar_negative_offset,
            width=0
        )
    )], filename='stick-chart')
```

[image: Stick chart made with Plotly]
https://plot.ly/~chris/15416

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this question is relevant again for someone, I should highlight that plotly now has a method for creating candlestick charts: https://plotly.com/python/candlestick-charts/

For example:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv')

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=df['Date'],
                open=df['AAPL.Open'], high=df['AAPL.High'],
                low=df['AAPL.Low'], close=df['AAPL.Close'])
                     ])

fig.update_layout(xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False)
fig.show()
```